# What is this small dialog box in the picture? How to remove it?

Tags: x11, login, sddm

[image: The dialog box]
[image: Bigger]

I was configuring [my KDE + i3wm hybrid setup](https://github.com/utkarshverma/dotfiles) and after adding a custom `~/.xsession`(which is [this commit](https://github.com/UtkarshVerma/dotfiles/commit/9ac590bb0b3c7fdfb4298e9340ff8b02b2e3c26f)), I keep seeing a small dialog box which appears after I enter a correct password. When I click on **Okay**, it properly logs me to my XSession as well.

I'd like to point out that earlier, I was using `.desktop` files to create an xsession using `Exec=env KDEWM=/usr/bin/i3 /usr/bin/startplasma-x11` which didn't produce this behaviour.

Could you please tell me what this dialog box is, and how to remove it?

#### Update

Upon further investigation, I've found out that the process is `xmessage`. Now the question is why it's opening and how to disable `xmessage` from opening on login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out what caused it. In my `.xinitrc` I had an unnecessary `startx` command, which was getting executed after KDE. The message was simply displaying that X server was already running or something of that sort(I'm being unclear because I couldn't see the exact message).